# How to manage multiple SQL schemas in a multi-tenant database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, multi-tenant, supabase

I am working on a SaaS and we decided to go for a Multi-Tenant approach with each tenant having its schema.

**What we have now:**

We have a stored procedures that we use to bootstrap a schema from scratch.

**Problem we are facing:**

If we only have this script and edit it, we can only apply changes to the future schemas.
We need to apply the changes to all schemas that have been created dynamically using the previously mentionned script.

What would be the best way to edit all existing schemas? While also adding this change to future schemas?

Thanks a lot!

edit: Trying to be a bit more clear

Comment: The problem sounds a bit nebulous, but have you looked at any tools like flyway for managing schema versioning? It, and similar tools, may be a path forward for you.

Comment: @JNevill, To be more precise: 
I have many schemas in a multi tenant database
I need to manage all the schemas.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

If your tenants operate under different users/roles, you can use [Row Level Security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) policies to keep everything separate without having to maintain multiple schemas. It works as if everyone was permanently given an additional `where` condition they use with every query, that they can't get rid of. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/P3PRj1zf):

```
create schema all_tenants;
create table all_tenants.employees (
  tenant_username text default current_user,
  id serial primary key,
  name text default 'John Doe');
insert into all_tenants.employees default values;
select * from all_tenants.employees;
```

| tenant_username | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | 1 | John Doe |

```
alter table all_tenants.employees enable row level security;--enables for all but owner
alter table all_tenants.employees force row level security;--enables for owner as well
create policy base_permit on all_tenants.employees as permissive for all to public
  using(true)
  with check(true);
create policy owned_rows on all_tenants.employees as restrictive for all to public
  using(tenant_username=current_user)--added to select/update/delete, checks existing rows
  with check(tenant_username=current_user);--added to insert/update, checks incoming rows
```

Now from a different user's perspective:

```
create role tenant1;
set role tenant1;
select * from all_tenants.employees;
```

the table will appear to be empty unless you add some records of your own:

```
delete from all_tenants.employees where name='John Doe';
insert into all_tenants.employees (name) values ('Tom Hanks');
select * from all_tenants.employees;
```

| tenant_username | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tenant1 | 2 | Tom Hanks |

The [policy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html) lets everyone create, read, update and delete only their own rows. Except superusers, who have [`bypassrls` privilege](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/role-attributes.html): you can see `tenant1` failed to remove the earlier `John Doe` record

```
set role postgres;
select * from all_tenants.employees;
```

| tenant_username | id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | 1 | John Doe |
| tenant1 | 2 | Tom Hanks |

Views can be defined [`with (security_invoker=true,security_barrier=true)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-privileges.html). Functions and procedures use [`security invoker`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) by default.

---

PostgreSQL also offers table structure [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html). If tables in your tenant-specific schemas all inherit from the tables in `v0` schema, an alteration to something in `v0` automatically cascades to all tenants. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cRqpQqMd):

```
create schema v0;
create table v0.employees (
  id serial primary key,
  name text default 'John Doe');

create schema tenant1;
create table tenant1.employees ()
   inherits (v0.employees);
insert into tenant1.employees default values;
select * from tenant1.employees;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |

```
alter table v0.employees 
  add column position text,
  add column first_name text default 'John',
  add column last_name text default 'Doe',
  drop column name;

select * from tenant1.employees;
```

| id | position | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | John | Doe |

It's good to know but while it does automagically cascade changes in existing tables in `v0` schema, there's no *schema* inheritance that would let you cascade creating or dropping tables to `tenant` schemas.